# Prove that m can be represented as the sum of the squares of two consecutive integers.

Tags: number-theory

Let $m\in \mathbb{N} $ be such that $m=\dfrac{u^2+1}{2}$ for $u\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $m$ can be expressed as the sum of the squares of two consecutive integers.

Any suggestion how to prove I would appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  $u$ must be odd to make $m$ whole.  Write $u=2k+1$

Answer (score 1):

$m$ is an integer so $u$ must be odd. Let $u=2k+1$. It follows that: $$m=\dfrac{(2k+1)^2+1}{2}=\dfrac{4k^2+4k+1+1}{2}$$ then
Hence
$$m=k^2+(k+1)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Just do it.

The sum of squares of two consecutive is $n^2+(n+1)^2=2n^2+2n +1$.

If we solve for $\frac {u^2+1}2=2n^2+2n+1$ then $u^2=4n^2+4n+1=(2n+1)^2$.

So if $\frac {u^2+1}2$ is an integer, then $u $ is odd.  Set $u=2n+1$ then and $\frac {u^2+1}2=n^2+(n+1)^2$.